# How to prevent pytest from executing all scripts in test folder?

Tags: python, pytest

I have the following project structure:

```
proj
  - src
  - tests
    - setup
      create_expectations.py
    __init__.py
    test_1.py
    test_2.py
    ...
```

Now, when I run `pytest`, it not only executes `test_1.py` and `test_2.py`, but also `create_expectations.py`.

I can verify that `create_expectations.py` is not imported from any other script. It's supposed to be a kind of "stand-alone" script that I run once.

`__init__.py` is an empty file.

My current understanding is that running `pytest` will only executes all files with "test" in its name. I would like to understand what I am apparently doing wrong.

EDIT:
`pytest --collect-only` reveals that only files with "test" in its name will be collected. This is exactly what I expect.

Comment: Put a `if __name__` guard in the script. Or better yet, don't mix scripts and modules

Comment: I could put ``if __name__`` in there, however, I would like to understand why pytest is executing the script.

Comment: It's probably being imported, maybe by one of the other scripts

Comment: No, it's not imported anywhere. My IDE (pycharm) reveals no usages at all.